# How do I keep navbar hidden until scroll down, and disappear when back to top of page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want the navbar on my page to be hidden until the user scrolls down the page; also, I'd like to keep the hamburger in the top left. I've been trying to use something along the lines of

```
    function showNav() {
      if (window.pageYOffset >= visible) {
      navbar.classList.add("visible");
     } else {
      navbar.classList.remove("hidden");
       }
     }
```

but it's not working and I think I am going about this the wrong way. Any help or suggestions would be welcome. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vp04aLc6/) link. Thanks again!

Comment: try this `(function($){
   $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 250){
     $('#navbar').hide();
    }else{
     $('#navbar').show();
    }
   });
})(jQuery);`

Comment: Your class name needs to be consistent - choose either "visible" or "hidden" and stick with it.

Comment: @Shoaib Thanks, but where do I put this? in the js file? or in the html? I tried html, at the bottom, but it didn't work. I haven't really used jQuery, so I'm probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @darrylyeo I don't think that function is ever called, but I will double check.

Comment: @Shoaib figured it out and your comment solved the problem! Thank you. If you write your comment as an answer, I will mark it.

Comment: If you like my comment then vote my comment.
Thanks.